# remove specific object with key and value

Tags: json, postgresql

here is an example that works but I cannot use it for my case

```
with entry(fields) as (values('{
  "login": {
    "value": "fred",
    "meta": {
      "indexable": true
    }
  },
  "password_hash": {
    "value": "88a3d1c7463d428f0c44fb22e2d9dc06732d1a4517abb57e2b8f734ce4ef2010",
    "meta": {
      "indexable": false
    }
  }
}'::jsonb))
SELECT
    jsonb_build_object(keys, fields -> keys)
FROM
    entry,
    jsonb_object_keys(fields) as keys
WHERE 
    fields -> keys @> '{"meta": {"indexable": true}}'
```

I am trying to run the following query but with no success

```
SELECT
    jsonb_build_object(keys, protection_config -> keys)
FROM
    ClickTrueTags,
    jsonb_object_keys(protection_config) as keys
WHERE 
    fields -> keys @> '{"pxg":{"trackingIds":[{"pixelId":"AW-12314555"}]}}'
```

where `protection_config` is

```
{"pxg":{"trackingIds":[{"pixelId":"AW-12314555","active":0}]}}
```

`protection_config` is a character varying

I need to remove this object  so I will get `{"pxg":{"trackingIds":[}}`
also how can I remove `pxg` entirely?

Answer (score 0):

I used the `#-` operator to remove the desired object, where I indicated the path to it in curly brackets:

```
with ClickTrueTags(protection_config) as (values('{
  "login": {
    "value": "fred",
    "pxg":{"trackingIds":[{"pixelId":"AW-12314555","active":0}]},
    "meta": {
      "indexable": true
    }
  },
  "password_hash": {
    "value": "88a3d1c7463d428f0c44fb22e2d9dc06732d1a4517abb57e2b8f734ce4ef2010",
    "meta": {
      "indexable": false
    }
  }
}'::jsonb))


SELECT protection_config #- '{login,pxg}'
FROM
    ClickTrueTags;
```

Output

```
-------------------------
 {"login": {"meta": {"indexable": true}, "value": "fred"}, "password_hash": {"me
ta": {"indexable": false}, "value": "88a3d1c7463d428f0c44fb22e2d9dc06732d1a4517a
bb57e2b8f734ce4ef2010"}}
```

If you do not delete the object:

```
SELECT protection_config
FROM
    ClickTrueTags;
```

Output

```
 {"login": {"pxg": {"trackingIds": [{"active": 0, "pixelId": "AW-12314555"}]}, "
meta": {"indexable": true}, "value": "fred"}, "password_hash": {"meta": {"indexa
ble": false}, "value": "88a3d1c7463d428f0c44fb22e2d9dc06732d1a4517abb57e2b8f734c
e4ef2010"}}
```